# In magento custom query update, how do I know if the query succeded

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to write some custom insert/update queries with custom logic like

```
$rs = $writeConn->query($myQuery);
```

And it works ok, but after this, how do I check if the query executed successfully or if there was an error? also how do I get the lastInsertId?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello Mage::log() is used for get query error.

Get last inserted id check code may be help you

$writeConn ->lastInsertId();